# Help with Eclipse shortcuts in Visual Studio C++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, eclipse, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Is there a way to import Eclipse keyboard shortcuts into visual C++ ? I am being forced to use this in my work and I miss my shortcuts.

If not then can you guys help me figure out these shortucts

1. Quick Outline View of the code: C-O in eclipse
2. Type Hierarchy : C-S-T in eclipse
3. Call Hierarchy  : C-H in eclipse
4. Find all the references of a word
5. QuickFix : C-1 in eclipse
6. Import all packages : C-S-O
7. Format all : C-S-F in eclipse
8. Move Lines : Alt+ Arrow

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same thing as you but on Visual Studio 2008. All I can say is that the experience was not fun. While I know Microsoft has upgraded the C++ intellisense in Visual Studio 2010, I don't know how much they improved the editor.

My recommendation is to just skip the headache and get [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/products/default.asp). It provides all the Eclipse features you want and then some.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [NavitageToTest](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1e900507-5eaf-42f6-88fa-a8264d3f4390/view/Reviews), [DPack](http://www.usysware.com/dpack/) and [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/), which works well. Using those two I have managed to configure these:

- QuickFix , Ctrl + 1 ,- View.ShowSmartTag
- Quick Access , Ctrl + 3 , View.QuickAccess
- Open Type, Ctrl+Shift+T - DPack.Solution browser
- Open Resource , Ctrl+Shift+R - DPack.File browser
- Call Hierarchy , Ctrl+Alt+H , View.Callhiearchy
- Quick Outline , Ctrl+O , DPack.Code browser.All
- Previous member, Ctrl+Shift+Up, Dpack.CodeNavigator.Prev
- Next member, Ctrl+Shift+Down, Dpack.CodeNavigator.Next
- Jump to test file (and back), Ctrl+J, NavigateToTestFile